# How do I keep my viewmodel in sync with inner domain objects' readonly properties?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm

Consider the following, dumbed down example:

```
// domain class
public class Sale
{
    public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }

    public decimal TaxTotal { get; set; }

    public decimal SaleTotal => SubTotal + TaxTotal;
}


public class ViewModel : ModelBase
{
    private Sale _sale;

    public decimal SubTotal
    {
        get { return _sale.SubTotal; }
        set 
        {
            _sale.SubTotal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public decimal TaxTotal
    {
        get { return _sale.TaxTotal; }
        set 
        {
            _sale.TaxTotal = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public decimal SaleTotal
    {
        ???
    }
}
```

The problem that I'm running into is that the `SaleTotal` property is a computed property, so there's no setter that would trigger the `OnPropertyChanged()` method in order to update the UI. Right now, I'm doing some kludgy logic where I just have atomic observable properties and when the inner `Sale` object is updated, I explicitly set the new values on those properties in order to update the display. This feels dirty and wrong and actually doesn't do me much good when I get into the same situation with collections (the domain collection is also readonly).

Is there a best (or common) practice for keep these two objects in sync without corrupting the domain class? The only thing I can think of is to use events which I think will ultimately end up doing the same thing that I'm doing now (i.e. the inner `Sale` object was updated, so the event handler just udpates all of the properties).

Comment: You can call OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SaleTotal)) when updating TaxTotal and SubTotal to update UI.

Comment: I did try this as well but for whatever reason, it wasn't working. It was referencing the inner object and all, but nothing was getting updated. I'm sure I made some other little mistake. If I can't find a better solution, I may go back and revisit this.

Comment: I would like to ask why you do not pass the property name to the 'OnPropertyChanged' method? Is this because of the simplified example or did you forget it?

Comment: @Martin Because it is handled in the base class with [CallerMemberName]. Using this, it is not necessary to explicitly specify the property name

Comment: Have you checked for any binding error messages in the output window? You could also test Dennis proposal by registering yourself to the 'PropertyChanged' event in the view model and check whether you receive an event for the 'SaleTotal' property when 'SubTotal' or 'TaxTotal' is set.